# Organize a structure of gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, metaprogramming, faker

I write the gem, it's the addition to `faker` gem (with russian functions like tax & vat et.c.)

So, I have a trouble: every piece of code is big, so I need to split it to logical parts.

IE I have `Inn` functionality to be called as `Faker::Russian.inn()`

So, I write

```
Dir['faker/russian/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }

module Faker
  class Russian
    extend Inn
  end
end
```

Else I have (at `faker/russian/inn.rb`) (which is required) this file

```
module Inn
  def inn ; puts 'inn goes here' ; end
end
```

But I have an error: `lib/faker/russian.rb:5:in <class:Russian>': uninitialized constant Faker::Russian::Inn (NameError)`

How can I avoid this error and successfully include code and `extend` all connected modules automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 is to refer to top level namespace when extend

```
extend ::Inn
```

Option 2 is to define Inn with correct namespace

```
module Faker
  module Russian
    module Inn
      def inn; end
    end
  end
end
```

In a gem option 2 is preferred to have all modules namespaced under this gem's top module. Imagine if you use option 1 and have an Inn module in app but not gem, you'll meet problem.

Comment: I use the 2nd way and still get this: `<class:Russian>': uninitialized constant Faker::Russian::Inn (NameError)`

Comment: 1st way don't work too. I get `<class:Russian>': uninitialized constant Inn (NameError)`. Maybe I don't require files well?

Comment: I see. There is a name conflict in #2. The module is named "Russian", while the class name is also "Russian". Give them suitable names and they should be fine.